# Disk Optimization not available in Disk Defrag of Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, performance

I have 2 SSDs that have the Disk Optimization not available error.

Tried everything with defrag commands and SATA/motherboard drivers. Nothing worked.

I wanted to share how I fixed this.

Comment: Windows 10 like written in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Windows command prompt as administrator and enter the command :

```
winsat formal
```

Now launch a Powershell command prompt as Aministrator

```
Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter c -ReTrim -Verbose
```

Confirm with Enter and wait during operations.
Disk optimization is now available with Windows 10 dfrgui.exe

Comment: For me, "Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter d -ReTrim -Verbose" produced "No MSFT_Volume objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to
'd'." It worked with c but not with d. In dfrgui, their current statuses are OK for C and Optimizing not available for D.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `dfrgui` to open the Optimize Drives dialog. That displayed drives C and W as SSDs with an OK status, and HDDs D and H as "Unknown" media type (presumably because they were VeraCrypt encrypted, but currently mounted) with Last Analyzed dates of "Never run" and Current status of "Optimization not available."

Then I ran `defrag h: /a` to analyze drive H. While that was running, I noticed that the Optimize Drives dialog displayed a progress percentage for drive H. When it finished, it reverted to "Optimization not available." But now it had a Last Analyzed date showing the current date and time. And in the CMD window where I ran `defrag`, it said, "You do not need to defragment this volume."

Possibly this explains the OP's finding that running `defrag` did not change the "Optimization not available" status in the `dfrgui` dialog. In my observation, `defrag` did change that status, but only momentarily.

It was odd that `defrag` found no need for defragmentation. Until I interrupted the process, the `dfrgui` dialog was reporting slow progress on a defragmentation effort that had been churning away for hours. Possibly that was consolidation, not defragmentation. When I ran `defrag h: /x`, the drive resumed a long consolidation process, again visible temporarily in the `dfrgui` dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Tried just about all the suggested fixes with no success.
Finally, Went into device manager, Removed the hard disk driver, Restarted, Voila, All good immediately.
Eugene C (aviator_888)

Comment: I ran Win-R > devmgmt.msc > Disk drives > right-click on the external dock containing drive H > Uninstall device. Then right-click on Disk Drives > Scan for hardware changes. That brought it back. But it did not change the status of drive H when I restarted dfrgui.exe: it still showed as Optimization not available.